# sorting integers by a priority queue

Tags: java, sorting, priority-queue

I want to write a program which can sort Items by Priority Queue

But the code below doesn't work and I dont know the problem

any help??
thanks in advance for your attention

```
public class SortingASequenceByPriorityQueue {

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pQueue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(1000, new Comparator<Integer>() {    

            public int compare(Integer w1, Integer w2) {                           
                if(w1.intValue()> w2.intValue())
                    return 1;
                else if( w1.intValue()< w2.intValue())
                    return -1;
                return 0;
            }        
        });    

         pQueue.add(12);    
         pQueue.add(1);     
         pQueue.add(5);    
         pQueue.add(22);    
         pQueue.add(3);    
         pQueue.add(2);    
         pQueue.add(124);    
         pQueue.add(14);    
         pQueue.add(111);    
         pQueue.add(9);    
         pQueue.add(30);    

        Object[] ar = pQueue.toArray();    
        for (int i = 0; i< ar.length; i++){    
            System.out.println(ar[i].toString());    
        }   
}  

}
```

The output is this :

1
3
2
14
9
5
124
22
111
12
30

Comment: This is specified in the doc. _"Returns an array containing all of the elements in this queue. The elements are in **no particular order**."_

Comment: It appears your objective is to sort a collection of integers in ascending order. Why do you need to use a `PriorityQueue` when there are other/better alternatives?

Comment: This is where reading the Javadoc would have answered your question.

Answer (score 7):

What you are effectively trying to do is heap sort. But you can't do that with `toArray()` which, for `PriorityQueue`, states

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this queue. The
>   elements are in no particular order.

What you'll want to do is remove the elements from the `PriorityQueue` one by one and add them to some array.

```
Object[] arr = new Object[pQueue.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = pQueue.remove();
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

which prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 12, 14, 22, 30, 111, 124]
```

This works because the `PriorityQueue` re-arranges itself when you add or remove an element to maintain the heap property.